# Where is the 1/8 CR apprentice in Volo's Guide to Monsters?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

I'm making my own monster list and I see in the back of Volo's under the Environment list it shows “apprentice” under “urban” with a CR of 1/8. In the CR list it only shows “apprentice wizard” with a CR of 1/4. Am I missing something? Where is the 1/8 CR apprentice?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

## You aren't missing anything. You can't find the CR 1/8 Apprentice Wizard because it's a typo.

The Apprentice Wizard in that table has been incorrectly assigned to the CR 1/8 line. As you've noted, if you check the "Stat Blocks by Challenge Rating" table the Apprentice Wizard is correctly listed as a CR 1/4 creature.

For further confirmation of this, the [D&D Monster Lists](http://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/DnDMonsterLists.pdf) PDF ([as published in November 2017](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/sage-advice/errata-november-2017)) has the Apprentice Wizard correctly listed as a CR 1/4 creature, attributed to Volo's Guide to Monsters. It also does not have a CR 1/8 version listed anywhere.

Comment: This is further supported by [this dnd beyond search](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-type=0&filter-search=apprentice&filter-cr-min=&filter-cr-max=&filter-armor-class-min=&filter-armor-class-max=&filter-average-hp-min=&filter-average-hp-max=&filter-is-legendary=&filter-has-lair=) if you want to include it to show there is no other "apprentice" creature

Comment: Yes I understand that is probably the issue. If it is then there are two typos. the environment shows apprentice and not apprentice wizard.

Comment: Also of note is the fact that "apprentice wizard" would be otherwise not mentioned in any environment

Comment: @Sdjz I'll note the second point when I get home. The search link though is both not future proof and requires users to go offsite, which I'd prefer to avoid.

Comment: I mean, it does stand to reason that a generic apprentice (like, apprentice cobbler? apprentice cheesemaker? whatever!) would be a lower CR than an apprentice wizard.

Comment: But an apprentice cheesemaker is, of course, stronger than a 0 CR plain _commoner_.  *[\*cough\*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvVCl.png)*

Comment: @mattdm where in the world did that stat block come from?

Comment: @illustro I made it really quickly using a site that lets you fill in homebrew templates.